# Custom fields that somehow get all the way to buildHook?

Tags: plugins, hook, customization, cabal

I would like to pass some custom, per-executable/library configurations (ideally a whole bag of key-value pairs, but at the very least a single `String`) from my `.cabal` file all the way to `Setup.hs`'s `buildHook`.

For reference, `buildHook`'s parameters are:

```
buildHook 
    :: PackageDescription 
    -> LocalBuildInfo
    -> UserHooks
    -> BuildFlags -> IO ()
```

So what I am hoping for is something in the `PackageDescription`'s `library` / `executables` field that gives me access to custom fields, without disrupting all other Cabal phases, that I could put in the `.cabal` file. Here's a made-up example that would basically be as good as it gets:

```
...

executable my-exe
  main-is: my-main.hs
  ...
  plugin-args:
    myplugin:
      foo: bar
      baz: quux
```

so I could retrieve all `myplugin` key/value pairs to get `"foo" |-> "bar", "baz" |-> "quux"` in some kind of associative data structure like `HashMap`.

**Note that I am already doing intense violence in my `Setup.hs`**, so any kind of hacky suggestions are welcome. If need be, I can override ALL `Setup.hs` hooks to ignore some settings in everything-but-`buildHook`, if that is needed for some solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although I haven't found it in the user documentation, there is [this nugget in the `BuildInfo` type](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/Cabal-3.0.0.0/docs/Distribution-Types-BuildInfo.html#t:BuildInfo):

> ```
> customFieldsBI :: [(String, String)]
> ```
>
> Custom fields starting with `x-`, stored in a simple assoc-list.

So it turns out you can write

```
...
executable my-exe
  main-is: my-main.hs
  ...
  plugin-args:
    x-myplugin: foo
```

and then access it with `lookup "x-myplugin" . view customFieldsBI :: (HasBuildInfo bi) => bi -> Maybe String`.

In particular, `Executable` and `Library` has `HasBuildInfo` instances, so you can just traverse the `PackageDescription` in `buildHook` and process their `String` value there.